# Sending Email upon registration

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using godaddy's domain in my ecommerce website. I want to send mail to the user when he signs up, for authentication, using my website's email account i.e. example@mydomain.com. Please give a hint how to do this.

Comment: are you facing an issue in generating the email or you want to update the sender email address?

Comment: Yes generating the email. I want to send email to the user to confirm his email address when he registers.

Comment: Do you mean you want to enable email verification, so any user can login only after they click on the email verification link?

Answer (score 1):

For account moderation (allow login only after email verification), there are lots of plugin, you can try [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/), it has moderation option.
For using your email address as sender, there are two ways, if you want to send VIA SMTP server you can use any [SMTP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/smtp/) like [Easy WP SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/) or any other as per your preference or if you don't want to use SMTP, you can mask the sender name and email by copying the following to functions.php

```
// Change email address
function my_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
    return 'johndoe@example.com';
}

// Change sender name
function my_sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
    return 'John Doe';
}

// Hook to WordPress filters 
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'my_sender_email' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'my_sender_name' );
```